# How can I capture **PRINT** and **PREVIEW** functionality in google drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

How can I capture **PRINT** and **PREVIEW** functionality in google drive API?

If I have a document in google drive and if I perform the below functionalities: 1) Edit 2) Download 3) Print 4) Preview 5) Trash 6) UnTrash - only edit, download, trash and untrash events are being captured in reports. Print and preview functionality are not being captured. I did try as an administrator from the google report screen (admin.google.com --> Reports --> Drive --> Click on Search) and I also did try from API related to drive SDK.

Question: Is there any additional setting required for PRINT and PREVIEW functionality to work?

**Steps to reproduce**
1) Even the google inbuilt report does not capture print and preview logs
   Login as admin --> Manage Domain --> Audit --> Drive --> Search

2) From code
    new Reports.Builder( HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential) .setApplicationName("TestApp").build().activities().list("all", "drive").execute())

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Scenario: If I have a document in google drive and if I perform the below functionalities: 1) Edit 2) Download 3) Print 4) Preview 5) Trash 6) UnTrash - only Edit, download, trash and untrash events are being captured in reports. Print and preview functionality are not being captured. I did try as administrator from the google report screen and I also did try from API.

Question: Is there any additional setting required for PRINT and PREVIEW functionality to work?

Comment: I am new to this website. I am sorry that I have to type it as a comment rather editing the original question. I have made corrections to the question now. Kindly let me know if you have any pointers.

Comment: that's much better already. Please include the code you used when you performed this similar action in the API. (If you also include a link to the API reference documentation for the method(s) you used, that would be excellent.)

Comment: I have edited the original post to have the sample line of code where the method is invoked and the report generated from google admin page. The first problem I am trying to fix is having the admin page UI to capture print and preview before addressing the API issue.